# How can I remove cells containing specific values in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

How can I remove cells containing specific values in Microsoft Excel. What I have is different columns and I just want to remove the cells containing 0 from that particular column. I found this link ***http://superuser.com/questions/324377/answer/submit*** but it searches for the whole sheet, i just need specific column

Cheers,

Comment: The above link is not working. Anyways Why not use Autofilter?

Comment: I'm not sure if delete means "clear" or "remove and shift cells up" or something else.  It doesn't seem to mean "delete the entire row."  If it's "remove and shift cells up" it's hard to imagine how that could be a good thing.  Anyways, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you highlight just the column in question, then you should be able to use replace and it will replace values in only that column. Alternatively, you could do the replacement in Google Refine, which has powerful clean-up features.